# How to set two services as alternative to each other?

Tags: dns, services, systemd-resolved

I'm using unbound instead of the normal resolver on a development server that I have

unfortunately - it crashes many times and service do not start

Ubuntu has it's own resolver as a service `systemd-resolved` for DNS but I disabled it to make `unbound` start as they both use the same port

now I need the normal resolver to exist **if unbound failed**

I could just change the port but my router uses the server as a DNS resolver to distribute development sites - so I have to keep it the same port

**How to set two services as alternative to each other on boot time?**